# How can I split a large CSV file into multiple files of rougly equal size using bash tools alone?

Tags: bash, csv, split

Note that the CSV file may or may not have multiple line breaks in each cell, and each split file must also be a valid CSV file.

I have tried using split, however, if I split by number of lines, it doesn't take into account that the CSV can have line breaks inside fields, and if I split by filesize, it sometimes cuts the last line of the file in half, meaning that it is no longer a valid CSV file.

You can find a test file here: 
https://pastebin.com/raw/pw9PF9U1

It looks like this:

```
post_title,tax:wcpv_product_vendors,post_content
Product title 1,Sample,"<div class=""productdetails"">
<h2 style=""margin: 0px 0px 15px; line-height: 1.2; text-align: center;"">Title</h2>
<p style=""color: #333333; margin: 0px; font-size: 13px; line-height: 23.1111px; padding: 0px; font-family: sans-serif, Arial, Verdana, 'Trebuchet MS';""><strong>Features:</strong></p>
<ul style=""padding: 0px 40px; margin: 0px; color: #333333; font-family: sans-serif, Arial, Verdana, 'Trebuchet MS'; font-size: 13px; line-height: 20.8px;"">
<li style=""list-style: none;"">Testing testing</li>
<li style=""list-style: none;"">One two three</li>
</ul>
</div>"
Product title 2,Sample,"<div class=""productdetails"">
<h2 style=""margin: 0px 0px 15px; line-height: 1.2; text-align: center;"">Title</h2>
<p style=""color: #333333; margin: 0px; font-size: 13px; line-height: 23.1111px; padding: 0px; font-family: sans-serif, Arial, Verdana, 'Trebuchet MS';""><strong>Features:</strong></p>
<ul style=""padding: 0px 40px; margin: 0px; color: #333333; font-family: sans-serif, Arial, Verdana, 'Trebuchet MS'; font-size: 13px; line-height: 20.8px;"">
<li style=""list-style: none;"">Testing testing</li>
<li style=""list-style: none;"">One two three</li>
</ul>
</div>"
Product title 3,Sample,"<div class=""productdetails"">
<h2 style=""margin: 0px 0px 15px; line-height: 1.2; text-align: center;"">Title</h2>
<p style=""color: #333333; margin: 0px; font-size: 13px; line-height: 23.1111px; padding: 0px; font-family: sans-serif, Arial, Verdana, 'Trebuchet MS';""><strong>Features:</strong></p>
<ul style=""padding: 0px 40px; margin: 0px; color: #333333; font-family: sans-serif, Arial, Verdana, 'Trebuchet MS'; font-size: 13px; line-height: 20.8px;"">
<li style=""list-style: none;"">Testing testing</li>
<li style=""list-style: none;"">One two three</li>
</ul>
</div>"
Product title 4,Sample,"<div class=""productdetails"">
<h2 style=""margin: 0px 0px 15px; line-height: 1.2; text-align: center;"">Title</h2>
<p style=""color: #333333; margin: 0px; font-size: 13px; line-height: 23.1111px; padding: 0px; font-family: sans-serif, Arial, Verdana, 'Trebuchet MS';""><strong>Features:</strong></p>
<ul style=""padding: 0px 40px; margin: 0px; color: #333333; font-family: sans-serif, Arial, Verdana, 'Trebuchet MS'; font-size: 13px; line-height: 20.8px;"">
<li style=""list-style: none;"">Testing testing</li>
<li style=""list-style: none;"">One two three</li>
</ul>
</div>"
Product title 5,Sample,"<div class=""productdetails"">
<h2 style=""margin: 0px 0px 15px; line-height: 1.2; text-align: center;"">Title</h2>
<p style=""color: #333333; margin: 0px; font-size: 13px; line-height: 23.1111px; padding: 0px; font-family: sans-serif, Arial, Verdana, 'Trebuchet MS';""><strong>Features:</strong></p>
<ul style=""padding: 0px 40px; margin: 0px; color: #333333; font-family: sans-serif, Arial, Verdana, 'Trebuchet MS'; font-size: 13px; line-height: 20.8px;"">
<li style=""list-style: none;"">Testing testing</li>
<li style=""list-style: none;"">One two three</li>
</ul>
</div>"
Product title 6,Sample,"<div class=""productdetails"">
<h2 style=""margin: 0px 0px 15px; line-height: 1.2; text-align: center;"">Title</h2>
<p style=""color: #333333; margin: 0px; font-size: 13px; line-height: 23.1111px; padding: 0px; font-family: sans-serif, Arial, Verdana, 'Trebuchet MS';""><strong>Features:</strong></p>
<ul style=""padding: 0px 40px; margin: 0px; color: #333333; font-family: sans-serif, Arial, Verdana, 'Trebuchet MS'; font-size: 13px; line-height: 20.8px;"">
<li style=""list-style: none;"">Testing testing</li>
<li style=""list-style: none;"">One two three</li>
</ul>
</div>"
Product title 7,Sample,"<div class=""productdetails"">
<h2 style=""margin: 0px 0px 15px; line-height: 1.2; text-align: center;"">Title</h2>
<p style=""color: #333333; margin: 0px; font-size: 13px; line-height: 23.1111px; padding: 0px; font-family: sans-serif, Arial, Verdana, 'Trebuchet MS';""><strong>Features:</strong></p>
<ul style=""padding: 0px 40px; margin: 0px; color: #333333; font-family: sans-serif, Arial, Verdana, 'Trebuchet MS'; font-size: 13px; line-height: 20.8px;"">
<li style=""list-style: none;"">Testing testing</li>
<li style=""list-style: none;"">One two three</li>
</ul>
</div>"
Product title 8,Sample,"<div class=""productdetails"">
<h2 style=""margin: 0px 0px 15px; line-height: 1.2; text-align: center;"">Title</h2>
<p style=""color: #333333; margin: 0px; font-size: 13px; line-height: 23.1111px; padding: 0px; font-family: sans-serif, Arial, Verdana, 'Trebuchet MS';""><strong>Features:</strong></p>
<ul style=""padding: 0px 40px; margin: 0px; color: #333333; font-family: sans-serif, Arial, Verdana, 'Trebuchet MS'; font-size: 13px; line-height: 20.8px;"">
<li style=""list-style: none;"">Testing testing</li>
<li style=""list-style: none;"">One two three</li>
</ul>
</div>"
Product title 9,Sample,"<div class=""productdetails"">
<h2 style=""margin: 0px 0px 15px; line-height: 1.2; text-align: center;"">Title</h2>
<p style=""color: #333333; margin: 0px; font-size: 13px; line-height: 23.1111px; padding: 0px; font-family: sans-serif, Arial, Verdana, 'Trebuchet MS';""><strong>Features:</strong></p>
<ul style=""padding: 0px 40px; margin: 0px; color: #333333; font-family: sans-serif, Arial, Verdana, 'Trebuchet MS'; font-size: 13px; line-height: 20.8px;"">
<li style=""list-style: none;"">Testing testing</li>
<li style=""list-style: none;"">One two three</li>
</ul>
</div>"
```

Also note each row of the csv has a ^M symbol at the end of it when I open it in vim. That may be useful to split correctly.

Comment: Please post a sample of the data with "line breaks inside fields" with expected output for testing. less than 10 records should be fine.

Comment: Hi again! I have added a sample file to the original question. [You can view it here](https://pastebin.com/raw/pw9PF9U1).

Comment: The `^M` is simply vim's display of `CRLF` (DOS) line ends. It's useful to know you should run it though `dos2unix`, but not for splitting the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one in awk. You provide it with filename and the maximum number of "lines" (for example `-v m=3`) you want in one file and it splits the file (based on your data) on lines that do not start with `<` so basically the header and the product title lines:

```
$ awk -v m=3 'NR==1{j=0}{if($0!~/^</){i++;if(i>m){i=1;j++}};print > "split-" j}' file
$ ls -1rt
split-3
split-2
split-1
split-0
$ cat split-3
Product title 9,Sample,"<div class=""productdetails"">
<h2 style=""margin: 0px 0px 15px; line-height: 1.2; text-align: center;"">Title</h2>
<p style=""color: #333333; margin: 0px; font-size: 13px; line-height: 23.1111px; padding: 0px; font-family: sans-serif, Arial, Verdana, 'Trebuchet MS';""><strong>Features:</strong></p>
<ul style=""padding: 0px 40px; margin: 0px; color: #333333; font-family: sans-serif, Arial, Verdana, 'Trebuchet MS'; font-size: 13px; line-height: 20.8px;"">
<li style=""list-style: none;"">Testing testing</li>
<li style=""list-style: none;"">One two three</li>
</ul>
</div>"
```

Explained:

```
awk -v m=3 '           # provide m
NR==1 {                # on the first record
    j=0                # set j to 0
}
{
    if($0!~/^</) {     # when a line not starting with a < is met
        i++            # increase line counter
        if(i>m) {      # if line counter exceeds max
            i=1        # reset it back to 1
            j++        # split file name index
        }
    }
    print > "split-" j # output
}' file
```

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer because it works perfectly for the sample I provided, however, in the actual file I am splitting, the new lines do not necessarily start with a '<' character. Also, I'm being picky, but ideally the split CSV files would also retain the header row. +1 for excellent awk skills!

Answer (score 0):

to split file.csv to 5 files

```
split -n 5 file.csv
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately this does not work, as it doesn't take into account that rows need to be completed in a CSV file.

Comment: @Luke How about `split -n l/5 file.csv`? The extra `l` expression prevents splitting inside rows

Comment: Almost @etopylight - I just gave it a try. Unfortunately It doesn't quite work because it doesn't take into account that there can be multiple lines within each field of the CSV. Running `split -n l/5 file.csv` does split the file up, however, the first and last lines of the split CSV files are in the incorrect columns.

Comment: @Luke Thanks for the feedback. Is it possible to get a sample of that "multiple lines within each field" csv? It will be quite helpful for us to do some testing

Comment: Hi again! I have added a sample file to the original question. [You can view it here](https://pastebin.com/raw/pw9PF9U1).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to support embedded newline characters,
then there is no easy way to do this right using Bash alone.
Otherwise `split` could have been a good choice.

You *could* implement a CSV parser (of your desired dialect) in Bash,
but it would be a lot of work for a fragile solution.

It's better to not use Bash for this,
but some other language with good library support for proper CSV parsing.
Such as Python,
which comes with a `csv` package included.

Comment: Okay then - Python might be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that still makes `split` usable.

The incentive here is to use a null byte character `\0` instead of a new line character `\n` as a record separator for splitting.

First, we can use `sed` to add a `\0` to the beginning of each line that does not begin with `<`

```
sed 's/^[^<]/\x0&/' file.csv > file_tmp.csv
```

Next, we can use `split` as usual

```
split -n l/5 -t '\0' --filter='sed 's/\x0//g' > $FILE.csv' file_tmp.csv split_
```

- `-n l/5` splits file into roughly 5 equal parts without splitting records
- `-t '\0'` uses the null byte character as a record separator
- `--filter='sed 's/\x0//g' > $FILE.csv'` removes all null byte characters from splitted files

Comment: This is an excellent answer - and it works perfectly for the test file I provided. Unfortunately in the real file I am splitting, new lines within the product description do not necessarily start with '<'. +1!